# delete data in firebase using React application

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Good day, I'm new React and firebase, Today, I using React and Firebase to display, add and delete data. I have some data in the firebase and display it. Now, I want delete some of the data, but I don't know. I create a button delete that whenever the user click it the data will be removed. Please help..

```
import React , { Component, Fragment }  from 'react';
class Form extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            db: [],
            name: "",
            city: ""
        }
        this.changHandle = this.changHandle.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        this.removeData = this.removeData.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { firestore } = this.props
        firestore.collection('cafes').orderBy('name')
        .onSnapshot((db) => {
            const data = db.docs.map(datas => datas.data())
            this.setState({
                db: data
            })
        })
    }
    changHandle(event){
        const {name, value} = event.target
        this.setState({[name]:value})
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            this.props
            .firestore
            .collection('cafes')
            .add({city: this.state.city, name: this.state.name})
    }
     removeData(id){
        this.props
            .firestore
            .collection('cafes').doc(id).delete();
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} autoComplete = "off">
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        value={this.state.name}
                        placeholder="Name"
                        onChange={this.changHandle}
                    /><br/>
                    <input 
                        type="text"
                        name="city"
                        value={this.state.city}
                        placeholder="City"
                        onChange={this.changHandle}
                    /><br/>

                 <button type="submit">Add user</button>
                 </form>
                 <p>Name:{this.state.name} {this.state.city}</p>
                {this.state.db.map(data => 
                    <div>
                    <li key={data.id}>{data.name} {data.city}</li>
                        <button onClick={() => this.removeData(data.id)}>Delete</button>
                    </div>)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Form
```

[MyApplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM15g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not setting an id for your document in firestore so it is just assigning a random one. In your handle submit button you need to do something like this:

```
        const id = new Date().getTime()
        this.props
        .firestore
        .collection('cafes').doc(id)
        .add({city: this.state.city, name: this.state.name, id: id})
```

Comment: id' is not defined  no-undef sir

Comment: it might not be undefined but it is not the same as the document name because when you are creating the document you are not setting the name as the same as the id, I bet when you go look in you collection you see a bunch of numbers as the document names, you need to specify the document name and set it as a property of the object so you can reference it later. try it...

Comment: ohh, do you mean I have to create an input which would the user input the id so I can reference it later ?